# react-native debug in chrome error

Tags: android, google-chrome-devtools, react-native

I use react-native for development Android application. When app is run, i trying to choose `Debug in Chrome` from react-native developer menu, then it app crashes, but in console, where i run command `react-native start` i see and error:

```
Launching Dev Tools...
 ERROR  Wrong length!
RangeError: Wrong length!
    at validateArrayBufferArguments (/Users/sergiigetman/IdeaProjects/mbc_kidsvod_client/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_typed-buffer.js:157:39)
    at new ArrayBuffer (/Users/sergiigetman/IdeaProjects/mbc_kidsvod_client/node_modules/babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_typed-buffer.js:247:29)
    at createUnsafeArrayBuffer (buffer.js:43:12)
    at createUnsafeBuffer (buffer.js:37:25)
    at allocate (buffer.js:199:12)
    at Function.Buffer.allocUnsafe (buffer.js:162:10)
    at new Buffer (buffer.js:93:19)
    at BufferPool.reset (/Users/sergiigetman/IdeaProjects/mbc_kidsvod_client/node_modules/ws/lib/BufferPool.js:57:26)
    at Receiver.endPacket (/Users/sergiigetman/IdeaProjects/mbc_kidsvod_client/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:247:68)
    at Receiver.finish (/Users/sergiigetman/IdeaProjects/mbc_kidsvod_client/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:483:12)
```

Haven't found any similar issue on stack and the internet.

Comment: looks like it's related to `babel-polyfill` and i even found similar issue, but it doesn't help https://github.com/zzarcon/microm/issues/22

Comment: With the same issue, loading manually on Chrome with "http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui" yields 'Site can't be reached', indicating that the local port is down. We're using an earlier version of react-native (0.22), but there's no indication that the issue is related to that.

Comment: @bitsand hi, thank you for response . Actually I just commented sentence that checks array buffer length and proceed further. I know it's not recommended but it works in my js world

Comment: are you using Hot Reload?

Comment: @bitsand i used. but i don't work on this task and react-native anymore

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to reproduce this error and it seems like an edge case as the result of running an older version of React Native (0.22.x) with babel-polyfill version 6.16.0. The error does not occur on current versions of React Native (0.40.0) and Babel Polyfill (6.20.0). We don't think it's relevant, but we're running node 7.2.0.

If you are unable to update your environment, one temporary workaround is to edit 'babel-polyfill/node_modules/core-js/modules/_typed-buffer.js' and modify the buffer checks on line 157 and 175 of that file:

```
if(numberLength != byteLength)throw RangeError(WRONG_LENGTH);
```

If you’re running babel-polyfill 6.20.0 then your file will be here:

```
node_modules/core-js/modules/_typed-buffer.js
```

We've been able to get our dev environment working by commenting this length check out, but caveat emptor, and you probably don't want to let this go into production.